# upload arduino code to arduino using winform c#

Tags: arduino

I build code editor for arduino with winform C# and i am doing very well with my project. My editor allows Autocomplete And provides help during programming.
My only problem is how to upload the code i wrote to arduino? 
for example, if someone writes on my editor this code:

```
int led = 13;

void setup() {                
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);     
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   
  delay(1000);               
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    
  delay(1000);               
}
```

How do I upload that to arduino with c#?

Answer (score 2):

The code the users input on your form application will need to be compiled first, then turned into machine language for the microcontroller in your Arduino to understand it. Since Arduino uses the avr-gcc compiler you could try to run it along with your form. Then, use avrdude to get the hex file, and use the SerialPort class in the .Net Framework in order to transfer the Hex file to the Arduino.

You could find more information about the upload process Click [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/BuildProcess).

I Hope this points you in the right direction, props for the project, it sounds really cool.